# Pgsql error: You might need to add explicit type casts

Tags: postgresql, heroku

My website is just working fine til i deployed it to heroku and the problem is heroku uses pgsql and I'm using mysql and laravel framework.

my query is

```
$patient = Patient::where('patient_address', 'ILIKE' ,'%' . $request->input)->where('patient_sex', 'ILIKE' ,'%' . $request->gender)->whereHas('users', function($q) use($vaccine_id){
        $q->where('vaccine_id','ILIKE','%' . $vaccine_id);
    })->get();
```

here's what I'm getting when I deploy it to heroku

`SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR: operator does not exist: integer ~~* unknown
LINE 1: ...ient_id" = "patients"."PatientID" and "vaccine_id" ILIKE $3)`

`HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts. (SQL: select * from "patients" where "patient_address" ILIKE %San Francisco and "patient_sex" ILIKE % and exists (select * from "vaccines" inner join "immunizations" on "vaccines"."VaccineID" = "immunizations"."vaccine_id" where "immunizations"."patient_id" = "patients"."PatientID" and "vaccine_id" ILIKE %))`

I have tried using cast like CAST(vaccine_id AS VARCHAR) and I' not getting the error but it doesnt return any result.

Comment: I don't know this API well, but `where "patient_address" ILIKE %San Francisco` is wrong, `San Francisco` should be in single quotes AFAIK.

Comment: it's a variable $request->input = san fancisco how do i put single quote on it?

Comment: I'm not sure, only I can tell you that if the query output is verbatim, then it's wrong.

Answer (score 33):

The problem is here:

```
$q->where('vaccine_id','ILIKE','%' . $vaccine_id)
```

looks like vaccine_id is integer, and you can not use operator ILIKE to integer. Try just '='

If you want to use LIKE, ILIKE or other text operator you must cast your data to text. In SQL it must looks like:

```
WHERE "vaccine_id"::text ILIKE val
```

instead

```
WHERE "vaccine_id" ILIKE val
```

Comment: I have my reason why i used ILIKE, i used like so even if where is false i can still run the other where conditions because i have chain where clause

Comment: Your error is `operator does not exist: integer ~~* unknown` - this is because vaccine_id is integer. And integer does not have operator ILIKE  (~~).

Comment: then why is it working with mysql? If it's working with mysql there should be a workaround with pgsql

Comment: Because mysql is not pure sql. At least as for me. Probably it cast by default data by some rules.

Comment: I have multiple where clause like for example
where('age', '2')->where('name', 'john')
if the age is false then it will return nothing
I still want to run the other where() regardless if the other where is false

Comment: operator '=' exists for all types, postgresql can cast second  type, but not first. i.e. "age" = '2' - postgres saw than "age" is int and cast '2' to int. But first argument you must cast manually

Comment: so i should write` $q->where('vaccine_id'::text,'ILIKE','%' . $vaccine_id) ` ?

Comment: No, because where - is a laravel method.  Probably something like $q->WhereRaw("vaccine_id::text ILIKE '%?%' , [$vaccine_id]")

Comment: I've tried it and it doesn't have any error but it looks like the where like is not doing anything or working

Comment: Why do you need ilike? If this integer may be use any other compare? ilike is case insesivity like and for what type cheking do you use it?

Comment: no i used $q->where('vaccine_id'::text,'like','%' . $vaccine_id)

I explained it to you awhite ago
if for instance i used where('age', '=', 1)->where('name', 'like', '%john%')
then to get my results back the age should be true
but if i use where('age', 'like', '%'.1.'%')->where('name', 'like', '%john%')
I would still get the result regardless of the age, if it's false or not. In localhost there's no problem because it's a mysql but heroku is using pgsql

Comment: $q->WhereRaw("vaccine_id::text ILIKE '?' ", [$vaccine_id])

Answer (score 9):

**You could do this:**

```
$q->where('cast(vaccine_id AS VARCHAR)','LIKE','%' . $vaccine_id)
```

**OR**

```
$q->where('cast(vaccine_id AS TEXT)','LIKE','%' . $vaccine_id)
```

Comment: I was facing this error while calling a procedure through JPA. Tried to cast with :: operator but didn't work, cast() worked without any issues. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

An explicit cast is a cast that you must specifically invoke, with either the CAST AS keywords or with the cast operator ( :: )

Comment: This does not answer the question.