# Using Model method in SQlite3 and PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, sqlite

In my Rails app, I do have SQlite3 for development and PostgreSQL for production. I have a habit class with belongs to category and Category has many habits. So, to let user search any category to see associated habits, I have developed a class method in habit model which goes into database and find all the habits according to searched category.

So, if I write,

```
def self.search(search)
  where("category_id LIKE ?", search)
end
```

It works perfectly fine in development but PostgreSQL gives 500 error in production saying:

> "No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might
>   need to add explicit type casts."

So, I googled about it and found solution ([Pgsql error: You might need to add explicit type casts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42149496/pgsql-error-you-might-need-to-add-explicit-type-casts)) and edited my method accordingly:

```
def self.search(search)
  where("category_id::text LIKE ?", search)
end
```

Now, it works perfectly fine in preoduction but SQlite gives me an error in development saying:

> "SQLite3::SQLException: unrecognized token: ":": SELECT "habits".*
>   FROM "habits" WHERE "habits"."user_id" = ? AND (category_id::text LIKE
>   '4')"

Tried a lot but couldn't solve this. Is there any way I can modify this method to work with both of the databases? or maybe is there any way I can tell my app to use which method in which environment?

Comment: are you searching for an id that fits a format, or will you always have the full id?

Comment: Hi @MichaelGorman.. I will always have a category_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a conditional on

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.instance_values["config"][:adapter]
```

Like

```
if ActiveRecord::Base.connection.instance_values["config"][:adapter] == "postgresql"
  puts "I'm using postgres!"
elsif ActiveRecord::Base.connection.instance_values["config"][:adapter] == "sqlite3"
  puts "I'm using sqlite!"
end
```

Comment: It does exactly what I need.And much simpler way than what I expected. Thanks a lot for the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it is just me, but IMO there is not point in using `LIKE` on columns that contain an integer. Therefore I would just use a normal `=`:

```
def self.search(search)
  where("category_id = ?", search)
end
```

Because that doesn't follow common Rails idiom, let's simplify this to  `where` with the hash syntax and use a scope instead of a class method:

```
scope :search, ->(search) { where(category_id: search) }
```

Which can be called from your controller like this:

```
Habit.search(params[:xyz])
```

Comment: Hi @spickermann, thanks a lot for your suggestion. Your suggested format looks really clean. But can we call this from the controllers? Because I do call class method search from two different controllers. Is it possible with this too?

Comment: Sorry, for being late, it was a really busy weekend. But thanks a lot for your tips. Tried it. It works like a charm! Very short and to the point!

Answer (score 0):

Let the database adapter do the work for you

```
def self.search(search)
  where(category_id: search)
end
```